# How can I simply write all console output of a command to a file, in the terminal?

Tags: bash, shell, file, pipe, stdout

I am trying to send all printed output of a `strace` command to a file. straces have a lot of console output since they print all the system calls of a command.

I have tried the most popular ways that I can find or think of, such as `command > file.txt` which does print output but then the output is not written to a file, same with `command | tee file.txt` Output is always printed but never written to a file. Is it because there is too much output or something? The first command definitely suceeds.

But my real question is what is the best way to do this and how can I get it done?

Many many thanks,
Milan

Comment: `strace -o filename yourcommand ...`

Comment: If you want both the command output and trace output, you need to redirect stderr as well: `> file.txt 2>&a`

Comment: @CharlesDuffy I upvoted up but actually you put ```...``` in code syntax which I think was a mistake, is confusing to read mistakes like that when you don't know the right command. Thanks both anyway!